# In-app purchase product id clarification

Tags: ios5, in-app-purchase

I have used "product id" like this "ADR123" in my application. I am getting "invalid product identifier" in-app purchase not working, whether this product id is valid or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the checklists of http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/invalid-product-ids/

Also refer to [this](http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/iphone-tutorial-%E2%80%93-in-app-purchases/) blog.

**Checklists:-**

- Have you enabled In-App Purchases for your App ID?
- Have you checked Cleared for Sale for your product?
- Have you submitted (and optionally rejected) your application binary?
- Does your project’s .plist Bundle ID match your App ID?
- Have you generated and installed a new provisioning profile for the new App ID?
- Have you configured your project to code sign using this new provisioning profile?
- Are you building for iPhone OS 3.0 or above?
- Are you using the full product ID when when making an SKProductRequest?
- Have you waited several hours since adding your product to iTunes Connect?
- Are your bank details active on iTunes Connect? (via Mark)
- Have you tried deleting the app from your device and reinstalling? (via Hector, S3B, Alex O, Joe, and Alberto)
- Is your device jailbroken? If so, you need to revert the jailbreak for IAP to work. (via oh my god, Roman, and xfze)

Answer (score 2):

u need to ensure that the bundle identifier is the one which is for the same app you have on itunesconnect which is having this product id added in in-app-purchase

Comment: My bundle id like this "Q4CCS9M524.com.companyname.applicationname" whether this is valid or not? my in-app purchase not working.

Comment: @samfisher Hi, is there any security check that the apple is doing to check whether the received product request is from the same app which is been registered in the iTunes connect for that product.

Comment: @PrasadDevadiga, logically yes they must.